# Python: Zip dict with keys

Tags: python

I have:

```
list_nums = [1,18]
list_chars = ['a','d']
```

I want:

```
list_num_chars = [{'num':1, 'char':'a'},
                  {'num':18, 'char':'d'}]
```

Is there a more elegant solution than:

```
list_num_chars = [{'num':a, 'char':b} for a,b in zip(list_nums, list_chars)]
```

Comment: Your solution is already elegant in that it is Pythonic, easy to read, and resembles the output. I'm not sure what else you could ask for :p

Comment: Do you mean that you want to have a sort of "macro" that will work on any such lists without having to change the names; e.g., if you pass it "list_foo", it will use the key "foo"?

Comment: @Vamana: nope, nothing like that.

Comment: Hey mods, *it's not duplicate*. Read the question carefully and look at the answers, if you know Python at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the initial lists are very long, you might want to use `itertools.izip()` instead of `zip()` for slightly improved performance and less memory usage, but apart from this I can't think of a significantly "better" way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

```
map(dict, map(lambda t:zip(('num','char'),t), zip(list_nums,list_chars)))
```

gives:

```
[{'char': 'a', 'num': 1}, {'char': 'd', 'num': 18}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a new variable which are the keys to your dict

```
from itertools import izip
nums  = [1,18]
chars = ['a','d']
keys  = ["num", "char"]      # include list of keys as an input
```

which gives a slightly more elegant solution, I think.

```
[dict(zip(keys,row)) for row in izip(nums,chars)]
```

It's definitely more elegant when there are more keys (which is why I started hunting for this solution in the first place :)

If you want, this tweak gives the same as a generator:

```
(dict(zip(keys,row)) for row in izip(nums,chars))
```